# du -sh : I don't get why these two results are different

Tags: linux, bash, du

I need to know the size of a folder and some of its sub folders. So I'm trying to use the **du** command.

I **cd** into the right directory and then try (in **bash**) :

```
[xxx@yyy TEST]$ du -sh .
4.1G    .

[xxx@yyy TEST]$ du -sh *AAA
3.2G    123_AAA

[xxx@yyy TEST]$ du -sh . *A
4.1G    .
2.7G    123_AAA
```

How is it possible that I get different results for the size of *123_AAA* (3,2GB then 2,7GB) with my second and my third command ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just to double check, this is GNU du, with no aliasing or funny folder names that start with dashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think du is aware of hardlinks. Try `du -shl . *A` .

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be it ! 
Do you know how I find which files are refering to the same inode ?

Comment: @Maxx `find ./ -xdev -type f -exec ls -i {} \; | sort -n | sed 's/%/%%/g' | awk 'BEGIN {n=-1} {if (n!=$1) printf "\n"; printf $1-n" "$0"\n"; n=$1}' | grep -B 1 ^0 | cut -d \  -f 3-`

Answer (score 0):

`du` processes arguments in order and keeps track of inodes so that they are only counted once (or twice if you use `-c`).  I don't see how `123_AAA` gets counted when it is listed after `.`, however.  The first explanation I thought of is that symlinks could be treated differently when listed on the command line, but that is with option `-D`, not the default.  Not crossing filesystem borders could be another candidate, but `-x` isn't enabled by default either.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't replicate this error, however, when checking the man pages:

```
SYNOPSIS
       du [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

So I think that you can only have one file argument at a time. Don't know why you're even getting a result for the last command:

```
wilhelm@server ~ $ du -sh .
2.1G    .
wilhelm@server ~ $ du -h wa
4.0K    wa
wilhelm@server ~ $ du -sh wa
4.0K    wa
wilhelm@server ~ $ du -sh . wa
2.1G    .
```

Comment: **You can give more than one argument.**  From `man du`: (du) _"Summarize disk usage of each FILE, recursively for directories."_ Try to do `su -sh wa .` instead and you should see the two lines one for `wa` and one for `.`. The size seems to be _divided_. Check it with `du -hsc wa .` and the total should be the same of `du -hs .`.

Comment: That may be correct, but in this specific scenario, the file wa is of neglible size @Hastur

Comment: Even if the file is of a negligible size `du` will show it to you. It has to be underlined that If you write `du -hsc . wa` you will see only the line relative to `.`. If you will instead write `su -hsc wa .` you will see a line for `.` and a line for `wa`. In both cases `-c` option will give you the (same) _grand total_ below. 
Btw: This comment are to little and in the previous command I want to write  `du -sh wa .` and not `su` ... missprint.

Comment: @Hastur read it that way *facepalm*
"[xxx@yyy TEST]$ du -sh . *A" does seem to be in the format "du -hsc . wa" though