# Inconsistent output of `du` command

Tags: linux, unix, centos, du

Why is the output of

```
du -sch ./
```

not identical to

```
du -sch ./*
```

E.g. I ran `du -sch` in my user's home directory and got 51GB but running `du -sch *` in the same directory results in 47GB. At first I thought maybe it's accounting for hidden files but that doesn't explain nearly 4GB of hidden files/folders.

I did read the manual for disk utility but I couldn't find an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> At first I thought maybe it's accounting for hidden files but that doesn't explain nearly 4GB of hidden files/folders.

How did you measure this? I think you *do* have 4 GB of hidden files/directories, or maybe even more (in a sense) if there are hardlinks involved.

This will tell you (I dropped `-h` to get more exact results; `tail` is to pass the "total" only; tested in `bash`):

```
du -sc ./{.[!.],..?}*  | tail -n 1   # hidden
du -sc ./*             | tail -n 1   # non-hidden
du -sc ./{.[!.],..?,}* | tail -n 1   # hidden and non-hidden by wildcards
du -sc ./              | tail -n 1   # directory as a whole
```

(syntax taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186219/108618)).

The first command is what you're missing. Get a sum of the first and the second result; it will be equal to the last two results, unless...

Unless there are hardlinked files between the hidden and non-hidden part. If so, the sum will be even greater because [these files will be counted twice when you sum by hand, but only once when `du` sums them for you in its single pass](https://superuser.com/q/895774/432690). In this case there is even more space taken by hidden files/directories than you think (although some of this space is "shared" with non-hidden part). Note there is [`-l` option of `du`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/du) that controls this behavior:

> `-l`, `--count-links`
> count sizes many times if hard linked

Comment: Hey Kamil, you are absolutely correct, there was a bunch of hardlinks that I had not considered. Thanks for the help and thanks for the info on du!! I'll make sure to add that to my notes :]