# Get the total size of all files of a given extension

Tags: bash, filesystems, find, du

I'm trying to get the total size of all the JPEGs in a particular folder, but no amount of combinations of options while piping to `du` seems to make this work:

```
find -type f -iname "*.jpg" | du -sch
166G    .
166G    total
```

All of them print the total of every file in the directory.

How do I get only the total file size of the files that I'm passing to `du`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only in one directory as it appears from your question, the simplest way would be to avoid piping altogether and instead do

`du -sch *.jpg`

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know this was possible, and didn't see it referenced anywhere else while looking. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `du` with the files as arguments you are limited by the length of the argument string (a few thousands files)(*). If you expect a large set of files, you have to provide the files in a list file using the `--files0-from=F` argument (you can use `-` for standard input):

```
find . -name '*.JPG' -print0 | du -msc --files0-from -
```

(*) And using `... | xargs du -c` won't help because xargs will chop the file list in batches and call `du` several times so you will have several sums...

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why simply piping to `du` doesn't work here (feel free to post answers elaborating on why), but I figured out that using `-exec` to execute `du` does work, and is also very fast with the `+` syntax.

```
find -type f -iname "*.mov" -exec du -ch {} +
```

This makes it much more efficient than piping would ever have been, especially since I was already using `find` to enumerate the files. It will also match the JPEG file extension no matter what case it's in.

Note that the above will print each file with its individual size before eventually printing the total itself. To print *only* the total file size for all the files, use:

```
find -type f -iname "*.mov" -exec du -ch {} + | tail -n1
```

Comment: Note: If there are many, many matching files, then `-exec du -ch {} +` will run more than one `du`. And then `tail -n1` will show you the result from the last one only and you may never know it's not what you wanted.

Comment: So are you saying it would be safer to use `\;`?

Comment: Not at all. Then you will run many, many `du`s and there will be no way to get a total, other than to add up what they all say. This is possible but note a single `du` is able to [count hardlinked files only once](https://superuser.com/q/895774/432690). If each file is processed by its own `du` then (after adding up) you will get an inflated result in comparison to what a single `du` would say.